# Unable to upload files using InvokeHTTP

Tags: apache-nifi

Im trying to upload a file into Box using the box api through Nifi invokeHTTP

I was able to upload using the postman and trying to replicate the cURL in Nifi InvokeHTTP attributes. But getting the error "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

How do i pass the boundary value to "Content-Type" in InvokeHTTP processor?

```
curl -X POST \
  https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer YXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------044837558017023342962729' \
  -H 'Cookie: box_visitor_id=5d1df6ab8c6781.68299959; site_preference=desktop' \
  -H 'Host: upload.box.com' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: d3a8b995-d3d7-473b-a117-981b22a72e69,9ca8ce6e-fe32-445b-b2c7-6722b4777a96' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F file=@/C:/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/test.txt \
  -F 'attributes={"name":"test.txt", "parent":{"id":"0"}}'
```

Following is the current processor configuration 
[InvokeHTTP configuration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjPG1.png)
[InvokeHTTP configuration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHknq.png)